# jQuery/JavaScript: Changing a variable only under certain conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

Ok, this is probably really a noob question, but I'll ask anyway!

At the moment, my function is defined like this:

```
function checkSize(size, otherSize, el) {
    if ($(el).width() <= 800) {
        size = otherSize;
    }

    alert(size);
}
```

but this wont work.
What does work is:

```
function checkSize(size, otherSize, el) {
    if ($(el).width() <= 800) {
        size = otherSize;
    } else {
        size = 5;
    }

    alert(size);
}
```

But that hardcoded value there is obviously really bad.
So actually, I want `size` only to be `otherSize` if the condition is true, else `size` should pass unaffected. How do I do it?

Comment: "`size` should pass unaffected" - excuse me ? In your first snippet, `size` will be exactly what was passed into the function invocation, when the condition does not match.

Comment: No problem. If the condition does not match, nothing should happen to the value of `size`.

Comment: code fine... show us where are u calling htis function

Comment: you tried to leave out the `size = 5;` overall?

Comment: wt is the problem with upper code?looks fine.

Comment: Maybe you have a variable type casting problem, have you tried to make sure the size you are using as argument is and integer and not a string?

Comment: Ah indeed, it was a casting problem. I've called the function with a string instead of an integer.

Comment: @aleation: How would that affect the assignment? Or the alert?

Comment: It wouldn't really affect the alert, but the if statement would always return false, because you cannot do aritmetic comparisons between a string and an integer, and the main functionality of his function was to compare two integers and change the value of the input depending on that comparison. as you can see in the comment above my last reply, it was indeed a type casting problem xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure the argument is an int before using it, but just in case you can try to force it into an integer if it's not:

```
function checkSize(size, otherSize, el) {
    if(typeof size != 'number'){
        size = parseInt(size, 10); // 10 is to define you are using a decimal system
    }

    if ($(el).width() <= 800) {
        size = otherSize;
    }

    alert(size);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

isn't this what you are looking for:

```
function checkSize(size, otherSize, el) {
    if ($(el).width() <= 800) {
        size = otherSize;
    } else {
        size = $(el)width();
    }

    alert(size);
}
```